# Phalcon - ::find() with relational conditions

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I am trying to fetch a model in Phalcon to get data with conditional parameters, in order to get data with static call `::find()` and passing parameters to it related to it's foreign:

```
ProductReports::find(array(
            "order.order_status_id = 6"
        ));
```

Is given the error:
`Error fetching`ProductReports`report: exception 'Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception' with message 'Syntax error, unexpected token ORDER, near to '.order_status_id = 6', when parsing: SELECT [ProductReports].* FROM [ProductReports] WHERE order.order_status_id = 6 (113)`

[image]

```
/**
 * Class ProductReports
 *
 * @Source('product_reports');
 *
 * @BelongsTo('order_id', 'Orders', 'order_id', {'alias':'order'});
 */
class ProductReports extends Model
```

Is there any way to fetch to static `::find()` filtering it's relation **instead doing a *foreach* loop** (filter single row with it's relation `order` alias)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use the QueryBuilder in that case. Make sure you define your relationship between your model with an alias. If you're using namespace, use the full path of your namespace (i.e. [Project\Models\Orders].order_status_id).

https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/8197/conditions-on-relation

Comment: What a shame! I thought the phalcon guys would have thought of another way to do it without using the query builder. Thanks

Comment: But this is pretty much the best way how it should be done. The syntax for example you proposed is very bad imho.